# Why does a named org-mode source code block get used when it was only declared and not used in another source block?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, literate-programming

it's required to have `#lang racket` to use the `substring` procedure. So I defined it like this:

```
#+NAME: directive
#+begin_src racket
#lang racket
#+end_src

#+begin_src racket :var directive=directive
(substring "test" 0 1)

#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: t
```

In the bottom block, I don't actually use it in the body, yet it works; and it doesn't work if I remove it. So the named block (directive) is being used in the bottom block. Why is it?

---

I hope the title makes it clear enough.

If there's a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do please tell me.

Comment: I presume that it happens because of the `:var directive=directive` header arg in the second block. On the LHS, `directive` is a variable (that is not used any further); on the RHS, `directive` is the name of a block that is evaluated in order to get a value to assign to the variable on the LHS. So the first source block is evaluated, presumably doing whatever is necessary for the second block to be able to use `substring`.

Comment: How exactly that works depends on the babel evaluator for racket, which is not available to me (maybe you should provide a link for it - I didn't find it in the usual package managers, but I did not search Github for it): e.g it might be running in  a session, so the results of the various code blocks accumulate in that session.